# Where does uname get its information from?

Tags: linux, kernel, source

Where does uname really get its information from?

I figure this is something that should be straightforward. Unfortunately, I can't find any header containing just that information.

Say someone wanted to change the basic output of `uname`/`uname -s`  from `Linux` to something else (essentially, renaming the kernel).

How would he/she go about doing that the proper way (that is, changing the source)?

Answer (score 33):

The data is stored in init/version.c:

```
struct uts_namespace init_uts_ns = {
        .kref = {
                .refcount       = ATOMIC_INIT(2),
        },
        .name = {
                .sysname        = UTS_SYSNAME,
                .nodename       = UTS_NODENAME,
                .release        = UTS_RELEASE,
                .version        = UTS_VERSION,
                .machine        = UTS_MACHINE,
                .domainname     = UTS_DOMAINNAME,
        },
        .user_ns = &init_user_ns,
        .proc_inum = PROC_UTS_INIT_INO,
};
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(init_uts_ns);
```

The strings themselves are in include/generated/compile.h:

```
#define UTS_MACHINE "x86_64"
#define UTS_VERSION "#30 SMP Fri Apr 11 00:24:23 BST 2014"
```

and in include/generated/utsrelease.h:

```
#define UTS_RELEASE "3.14.0-v2-v"
```

UTS_SYSNAME may be defined in include/linux/uts.h

```
#ifndef UTS_SYSNAME
#define UTS_SYSNAME "Linux"
#endif
```

or as a #define in makefiles

Finally, the hostname and domainname can be controlled by /proc/sys/kernel/{hostname,domainname}. These are per UTS namespace:

```
# hostname
hell
# unshare --uts /bin/bash
# echo test > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname 
# hostname
test
# exit
# hostname
hell
```

Comment: This is generally a good and complete answer, but it may be worth while answering the poster's question directl. I believe this would amount to - change the relevant entry in the relevant file and recompile. You wrote "or as a #define in makefiles". Can you elaborate?

Comment: +1 for `unshare`.  Somehow I managed to miss this command until today.  Thanks!

Comment: And `include/generated/compile.h` is generated by `scripts/mkcompile_h`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/485962/32558

Answer (score 28):

The `uname` utility gets its information from the `uname()` system call.  It populates a struct like this (see [`man 2 uname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html)):

```
       struct utsname {
           char sysname[];    /* Operating system name (e.g., "Linux") */
           char nodename[];   /* Name within "some implementation-defined
                                 network" */
           char release[];    /* Operating system release (e.g., "2.6.28") */
           char version[];    /* Operating system version */
           char machine[];    /* Hardware identifier */
       #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
           char domainname[]; /* NIS or YP domain name */
       #endif
       };
```

This comes directly from the running kernel.  I would assume all of the information is hard-coded into it, except perhaps `domainname` (and as it turns out, also `nodename`, `machine`, and `release`, see comments). The release string, from `uname -r`, can be set via configuration at compile time, but I doubt very much the sysname field can -- it's the Linux kernel and there's no conceivable reason for it to use anything else.

However, since it is open source, you could change the source code and recompile the kernel to use whatever sysname you want.

Comment: The `domainname` field is set by the [`domainname`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/domainname.1.php) command, using the [`setdomainname`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/setdomainname.2.php) system call. Similarly, the `nodename` field is set by the [`hostname`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/domainname.1.php) command, using the [`sethostname`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/sethostname.2.php) system call. (The `nodename` / `hostname` value may be stored in `/etc/nodename`.)

Comment: This is irrelevant — the question asked where to change this. So yes, the `uname` command gets its information from a system call. And where does the system call get its information? (Answer, provided by other posters here: it's hard-coded in the kernel at compile time.)

Comment: @Gilles: What's irrelevent? If the answer is "provided by other posters here: it's hard-coded into the kernel..." note I've said the exact same thing: "This comes directly from the running kernel. **I would assume all of the information is hard-coded into it...since it is open source, you could change the source code and recompile the kernel to use whatever sysname you want**.  It is *not* a config option.

Comment: Some fields there (`nodename`, obviously, and also `machine`) can be changed at runtime, on a per-process basis. The assumption that your conclusion rests on is wrong. It happens to be true for `sysname`, but you need to dig deeper to find this out.

Comment: @Gilles O_O? The assumption is obviously correct, as the other answers bare out: it is a hard coded define which could be altered via make or editing the source itself.

Comment: @goldilocks You stated that “I would assume all of the information is hard-coded into it, except perhaps `domainname`” — no, `domainname` isn't the only one that isn't hard-coded, there's also `nodename` and `machine`. With at least three fields out of six that can change, why would you assume that the other three cannot change?

Comment: @Gilles : Because the question was about *sysname*, and I felt safe about that.  It says `Linux` because that's what it is, why would it say anything else? +1 to the other answers that confirmed this (I would have done so if prodded by the OP; "it's hard-coded" seems generally sufficient).

Comment: @goldilocks Why would `machine` ever change? It might not be hardcoded into the kernel because it might adapt to the hardware, but surely then it would be set at boot time and wouldn't change after that. But no: it can be set per process (e.g. to report `i686` to 32-bit processed on x86_64). By the way, `release` can also be customized per process to some extent (try `setarch i686 --uname-2.6 uname -a`).

Comment: @Gilles I've edited `machine`, `nodename`, and `release` into the question with a reference to the comments.  Again, the question wasn't actually about all those fields.

Answer (score 8):

With the help of a [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/%20Linux%20Cross%20Reference) and your mention of `/proc/sys/kernel/ostype`, I tracked `ostype` to [include/linux/sysctl.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sysctl.h),
where a comment says that names are added by calling `register_sysctl_table`.

So where is that [called from](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=register_sysctl_table)? One place is [kernel/utsname_sysctl.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/utsname_sysctl.c), which includes [include/linux/uts.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/uts.h), where we find:

> ```
> /*
>  * Defines for what uname() should return 
>  */
> #ifndef UTS_SYSNAME
> #define UTS_SYSNAME "Linux"
> #endif
> ```

So, as the [kernel documentation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20-rc3/source/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt#L571) states:

> The only way to tune these values is to rebuild the kernel

:-)

Answer (score 7):

As commented elsewhere, the information come with the `uname` syscall, which information is hard-coded in the running kernel.

The version part is normally set when compiling a new kernel by the [Makefile](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Makefile):

```
VERSION = 3
PATCHLEVEL = 15
SUBLEVEL = 0
EXTRAVERSION =
```

when I had time to play compiling my kernels, I used to add things over there in EXTRAVERSION; that gave you `uname -r`  with things like `3.4.1-mytestkernel`.

I do not fully understand it, but I think that the rest of the information is setup in the `Makefile` also around line 944:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# KERNELRELEASE can change from a few different places, meaning version.h
# needs to be updated, so this check is forced on all builds

uts_len := 64
define filechk_utsrelease.h
    if [ `echo -n "$(KERNELRELEASE)" | wc -c ` -gt $(uts_len) ]; then \
      echo '"$(KERNELRELEASE)" exceeds $(uts_len) characters' >&2;    \
      exit 1;                                                         \
    fi;                                                               \
    (echo \#define UTS_RELEASE \"$(KERNELRELEASE)\";)
endef

define filechk_version.h
    (echo \#define LINUX_VERSION_CODE $(shell                         \
    expr $(VERSION) \* 65536 + 0$(PATCHLEVEL) \* 256 + 0$(SUBLEVEL)); \
    echo '#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) (((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c))';)
endef

$(version_h): $(srctree)/Makefile FORCE
    $(call filechk,version.h)

include/generated/utsrelease.h: include/config/kernel.release FORCE
    $(call filechk,utsrelease.h)

PHONY += headerdep
headerdep:
    $(Q)find $(srctree)/include/ -name '*.h' | xargs --max-args 1 \
    $(srctree)/scripts/headerdep.pl -I$(srctree)/include
```

For the rest of the data, the `sys_uname` syscall is generated using macros (in a quite convoluted way), you can start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799263/where-is-the-implementation-of-functions-in-syscalls-h-within-linux-kernel)  if you feel adventurous.

Probably the best way to change such information is writing a kernel module to override the `uname` syscall; I never did that but you can find info [in this page](http://kghosh.yoll.net/) at section 4.2 (sorry, no direct link). Notice however that that code is referring to a quite old kernel (now Linux kernel has `uts` namespaces, whatever they mean) so you will need to change it probably a lot.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. 

I already knew it had something to do with uname. However, what I can't fathom is how and where inside the source the string "Linux" is defined. All I know is where I can find that information during runtime (it's contained inside /proc/sys/kernel/ostype). 

Finding out how exactly the kernel itself knows it's proper name would be one of the more interesting things, I'd say.

Comment: @user237251 how many instances of the word "Linux"
 occur in the kernel source in string contexts? If it's not that many, you could just examine the results of a textual search and see where that leads you.

Comment: @JAB Way too many. Fortunately, someone on kernelnewbies.org helped me solve the "mystery". Linux gets its sys name from /include/Linux/uts.h. See here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/uts.h?v=3.10

Answer (score 3):

**`scripts/mkcompile_h`**

In v4.19, this is the file that generates `include/generated/compile.h`, and contains several interesting parts of `/proc/version`: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/scripts/mkcompile_h

- the `#<version>` part comes from the `.version` file on the build tree, which gets incremented whenever link happens (requires file / config changes) by `scripts/link-vmlinux.sh`.

  It can be overridden by the `KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION` environment variable:

  ```
  if [ -z "$KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION" ]; then
      VERSION=$(cat .version 2>/dev/null || echo 1)
  else
      VERSION=$KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION
  fi
  ```
- the date is just a raw `date` call:

  ```
  if [ -z "$KBUILD_BUILD_TIMESTAMP" ]; then
      TIMESTAMP=`date`
  else
      TIMESTAMP=$KBUILD_BUILD_TIMESTAMP
  fi
  ```

  and similarly the username comes from `whoami` (`KBUILD_BUILD_USER`) and hostname from `hostname` (`KBUILD_BUILD_HOST`)
- The compiler version comes from `gcc -v`, and cannot be controlled it seems.

Here is a how to change stuff version of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424174/how-to-customize-or-remove-extra-linux-kernel-version-details-shown-at-boot

Answer (score 2):

While I couldn't find anything in the source to indicate this, I believe it uses the uname syscall.

`man 2 uname`

should tell you more about it. If that's the case it's getting the information directly from the kernel and changing it would probably require recompilation.

You could change the binary for you uname to do whatever you want though, just write over it with w/e program you please. The downside being some scripts rely on that output.

Comment: If you do `strace uname`, it will confirm that the `uname` system call is used.

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to change uname would be to change compile headers and re-compile like others suggested. But I am not sure why you would want to go through that much trouble when you can do something like,

```
alias uname 'uname \\!* | sed s/2.6.13/2.6.52/'
```

or even

```
alias uname 'echo whatever'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rmano](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52205/rmano)'s answer got me partway, but the real magic is easier discovered by passing the `Q=` option in your `make` commandline in the kernel source directory. it lets you see the details, one of which is a call to a script: `echo "4.4.19$(/bin/sh ./scripts/setlocalversion .)"`. executing that same snippet gives the kernel release number, `4.4.19-00010-ge5dddbf`. if you look at the script, it determines the number from the versioning system, and running it with `bash -x` shows the exact process:

```
+++ git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD
++ head=e5dddbf
+++ git describe --exact-match
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ false
+++ git describe
++ atag=release/A530_os_1.0.0-10-ge5dddbf
++ echo release/A530_os_1.0.0-10-ge5dddbf
++ awk -F- '{printf("-%05d-%s", $(NF-1),$(NF))}'
++ git config --get svn-remote.svn.url
++ git diff-index --name-only HEAD
++ grep -qv '^scripts/package'
++ return
+ res=-00010-ge5dddbf
+ echo -00010-ge5dddbf
-00010-ge5dddbf
```

what this shows me is that if I want to build a kernel module to work with my running kernel, I'm on the wrong tagged release and the wrong commit. I need to fix that, and build at least the DTBs (`make dtbs`) in order to create the generated files with the right version number.

---

turns out, even that wasn't enough. I had to replace `scripts/setlocalversion` to one that simply does:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -0710GC0F-44F-01QA
```

then rebuild the autogenerated files:

```
make Q= ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- dtbs
```

then I could build Derek Molloy's [sample driver](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device/) and was able to `insmod` it successfully. apparently the warning about `Module.symvers` not being present didn't matter. all Linux was using to determine if the module would work was that localversion string.