# Modifying linux kernel GNU

Tags: linux, kernel, source

How can I modify the kernel by modifying the GNU/linux line

I need to change the finish line:

```
#1 SMP Sun Mar 19 19:09:00 UTC 2017 i686 GNU/Linux
#1 SMP Sun Mar 19 19:09:00 UTC 2017 i686 windows/windows
```

I can not find the line, I do not know if it is possible to modify it from the kernel source, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about modifying `uname` output, which is based on a system call, see [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136959/where-does-uname-get-its-information-from)

If you'd like to compile your own custom kernel, I'd recommend reading up on http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/kernel-custom.html

If you're just talking about making it look different, you could always pipe it into sed

`uname -a | sed 's/GNU\/Linux/Windows\/Windows/'`